# Preserving the configuration file during RPM update

Tags: rpm

I'm trying to make my RPM to preserve configuration files, if these exist.

The behavior should be like MySQL or Lighttpd, where new configuration files, if the old ones are present, are saved with the extension `.rpmnew`.

Any idea how to best to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RPM does this automatically for files marked with the `%config` attribute in your spec file.  Exactly what happens depends on whether the configuration file has been modified locally and whether you have used just `%config` or `%config(noreplace)`.

Read more [here](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html).

Comment: For less specific, but more 'official' see: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Spec